# How do you "extend" BLAS subroutines?

Tags: math, fortran, linear-algebra, lapack, blas

Typically, a BLAS subroutine is defined for a certain unique operation. For instance,

`DAXPY` is necessarily `y <-- ax + y`

`DSCAL` is necessarily `x = ax`.

What I wish to achieve is:

`z = ax+by` and `y = ax`.

**How do I "extend" the subroutines of BLAS so that I can do the above?**
(These operations do not necessarily follow each other)

I have tried:

- Declaring a dummy and then `DCOPY`ing the dummy to the desired vector. Like, `DCOPY(dummy,x); DSCAL(a,dummy),DCOPY(y,dummy)`
- Creating my own OpenMP implementation
- Using tricks like, `DCOPY(y,a*x)` for y=ax

But the problem is, none of these methods seem to give me a conclusive answer for which is the best way of getting around this problem. I know I should "Profile, Profile, Profile" rather than asking but I have tried all of that but everytime I change the vector a little, what was the best method earlier suddenly becomes the worst or vice versa.

Also,

- My intention is to bring about the best performance possible.
- I know that optimizing these operations won't probably give me much performance boost but I'm trying to save every picosecond that I can.
- FWIW, I am linking to Intel MKL

Comment: Why do you need `y`? Are you really only trying to calculate `z = ax + bax`?

Comment: Really, I think there is no good answer, because such things can change depending on how long are the vectors, what hardware you are running on, compiler and library versions, etc etc. Also, if you are using a recent intel fortran (12.2), I sometimes find simple intrinsic operations to work as fast or faster than MKL calls.

Comment: @talonmies, they are 2 different operations which occur at many places in my code. Not necessarily juxtaposed.

Comment: @laxxy, I think I'd be more than happy if someone told me which method won't work. Every time I change my matrix, I spend 2 hours finding out which method works well.

Comment: You probably have a good idea what the candidate methods are already :) Now, if things change a lot and often, you can try programming several alternatives, and after you change things, run a small benchmark when you change things to automatically pick one of them, e.g. with a shell script or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your explanation of y <- a x, you could remove one excessive copying by using DCOPY(y,x); DSCAL(a,y).

Second, OpenMP IMHO is not a solution for this kind of problems, because they are "memory bound". The penalty lies in pipelining memory accesses with computations and vectorization, which uses more bandwidth by using vector memory accesses. Hand-tuned code should be very complex because of (branch-prediction, cache policies, register file configurations, etc.) You need something like Atlas library of R. Clint Whaley which automatically generates optimized operation implementation for a particular platform. AFAIK, there is BLAST standard (2001), maybe you'll find similar variants of the operations you've presented. May be you need to e-mail them to add these operations to their autotuner.

As a starting point, I would recommend you use the following implementation of z = ax+by.
In this case z is written anyway, provided x and y are readonly, you could use:
DCOPY(z,y); DSCAL(b,z); DAXPY(a, x, z);

You could also read the articles about ATLAS project, which contain the main considerations about the key aspects of code optimization (the presence of madd operation, cache characteristics, register file configuration, instruction latencies, etc.) and try to write something like a codegenerator for your operations to pipeline execution of various operations and perform a search between various variants.

It's an interesting topic, I've been implementing BLAS on a heterogeneous multicore architectures with explicitly-managed memory hierarchies, like a Cell processor. I wish you a good luck! Hope my answer is useful!

Comment: I have tried ATLAS but in most cases, it was awfully slow as compared to Intel MKL. I'll probably give it another shot. What bugs me the most is at times, with full dense vectors of length 100k, a simple a=b Fortran operation is much faster than DCOPY(100k,a,1,b,1)!

Comment: As far as I understand your situation BLAS does not provide the operations you want. I do not state ATLAS is superior than MKL (a man is always more powerful than a machine in solving complex problems :)). I've just said, you could use an approach they've taken to write something similar to help you find a suitable implementation on your machine. As of copying operations, maybe it's more convenient to solve the tasks described using a tiled algorithm (perform it block-by-block) reducing the task size and choosing the best tile size in terms of time to solution?

Comment: My OpenMP implementation was on similar lines. It is a fairly simple looking code which SECTIONS out a certain amount of work per thread. To top it, I had made a few preliminary microoptimizations to ensure that my memory flow and work sharing was optimal. But Alas, no use.

Comment: ATLAS has always been written by Clint Whaley.

Comment: OpenMP is absolutely a solution for bandwidth bound problems.  In many cases, you need to use more than one core per node to saturate peak bandwidth.  For example, on Blue Gene/Q, you need 16 threads to max out the STREAM triad benchmark.

Comment: @Jeff Never had an experience of trying to squeeze every drop from a main memory-LLC$ using several threads, managing such things as several outstanding cache misses and memory bank conflicts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MKL, you can use the extension DAXPBY, which does `y <-- ax + by`.  Your operations then become:

```
`z = ax + by`: DCOPY(n,z,1,y,1), then DAXPBY(n,a,x,1,b,z,1)
`y = ax`: DAXPBY(n,a,x,1,0,y,1)
```

You might also try letting the compiler vectorize simple scalar code; in theory these simple operations should be amenable to auto-vectorization (of course, in practice...)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you write your own routines using Fortran 95 array notation and see if the compiler is able to generate decent code.  I suspect that it will, because bandwidth-limited operations are nearly maxed out by the naive implementation, i.e. the optimized BLAS1 library implementation written by gurus will probably not be much faster than unoptimized Netlib BLAS1 unless the data is resident in cache already (in which case, vectorization will have some effect).

I have made such comparisons in the past and found that, for any vector not resident in cache, the difference between optimized and unoptimized BLAS1 style routines is negligible.